# space next to images in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I am having troubles with outlook

There seems to be around about a 5px space on the right side of my images as shown in the photo below

[image]

I have highligted the images and it is showing this space

This is only happening on outlook

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;width: 600px;" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
      <tr>
        <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="/* padding: 9px; */mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightContentOuter" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="mcnCaptionRightContentInner" style="/* padding: 0 9px; */mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="mcnCaptionRightImageContent" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
                          <img alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f567dd1675744adea35c088a5/images/676cbf8b-8c4b-49fa-8cdf-0cf1b15a5ccd.png" style="max-width: 142px;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: bottom;"
                          width="132">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;width: 425px;margin-top: 15px;"
                  width="396">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;word-break: break-word;color: #202020;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;line-height: 125%;" valign="top"><span style="font-size:20px"><strong>Top things to do
            in retirement</strong></span>
                          <br>
                          <span style="font-size:14px">Read our blog on the top things to do
            when you retire. Whether it’s moving closer to your family,
            travelling, volunteering or trying a new sport or hobby.<br>
            <br>
            <a href="http://www.hiltonsmythe.com" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #2BAADF;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank"><img align="left" data-file-id="3021085" height="53" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f567dd1675744adea35c088a5/images/588b19eb-10f7-4600-ab33-05dbfb31143a.png" style="border: 0px initial;width: 150px;height: 53px;margin: 0px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="150"></a></span>
                          <br>
                          <br>&nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

The first things I would try are putting an explicit width="132" on the  containing the image, and perhaps the  surrounding it. Outlook will tend to pad tables and cells to fill up the space, if no size is defined.